# Universal property of the set of injections in the category of sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, universal-property

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, the function set $B^A$ is characterized by the universal property that the functor $(-)^A:\mathrm{Set} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is the right adjoint of the functor $(-)\times A:\mathrm{Set} \to \mathrm{Set}$. What is the universal property of the set of injections between two sets $A$ and $B$ in the category of sets, if any such universal property exists?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Inj}{\operatorname{Inj}}\newcommand{\Set}{\mathrm{Set}}$**Maps $X \to \Inj(A,B)$ correspond to monomorphisms $A \times X \to B \times X$ in the slice $\Set/X$, which can be thought of as “$X$-indexed monomorphisms $A \to B$”.**

This isn’t hard to check: the main tool is that for any objects over $X$, say $A' \to X$ and $B' \to X$, maps $f : A' \to B'$ over $X$ correspond to $X$-indexed families of maps between their fibers $f_x : A'_x \to B'_x$, and such $f$ is a mono in $\Set/X$ precisely if each $f_x$ is a mono (equivalently, injection) in $\Set$.

There’s a general philosophical point here. Interesting universal properties are often most naturally described in terms of *slices* of the ambient category; an “$X$-indexed family of whatsits” will usually be a whatsit in $\mathcal{E}/X$.  Objects of $\mathcal{E}/X$ are viewed as $X$-indexed families of objects of $\mathcal{E}$ — this “relative viewpoint” was famously exploited and popularised by Grothendieck, in the category of schemes, i.e. the “spaces” of algebraic geometry — and if you started with plain objects of $\mathcal{E}$ (like your original $A$ and $B$), then to mention them in $\mathcal{E}/X$, you use the *constant* families of objects $A \times X \to X$, as above.

Comment: +1. So I guess the general version is: If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with products and $A,B$ are two objects, then we have a functor $X \mapsto \mathrm{Mono}_{\mathcal{C}/X}(A \times X , B \times X)$, and a representing object is called a monomorphism classifier of $A$ to $B$ and may be denoted $[A,B]_{\text{mono}}$? In case it exists, it is always a subobject of the internal hom $[A,B]$ (in case that exists), since $\mathrm{Mono}_{\mathcal{C}/X}(A \times X , B \times X)$ embeds into $\hom(A \times X, B) = \hom(X,[A,B])$.